# Highlighting or coloring certain words / substrings appearing in a larger string

Tags: graphics, string-manipulation

I have one longer string, `longString`, and a set $S$ of shorter strings `{ss1,ss2,ss3,...}`.  I'd like to print out `longString` but where the positions of the shorter strings are indicated in some nice way.  For example, perhaps we could color the characters in the longer string with a specific specified color for each shorter string.  I.e. where would would have an array like `{{ss1,'Red'},{ss2,'Green'},{ss3,'Blue'},...}` and would then color words appearing in `longString` `Red` if the word is `ss1`, `Blue` if the word is `ss2`, and so forth.  The idea would be to shade `Brown` / etc. overlap regions if they occur.

Is this possible?

One can use `StringPosition` to return the first and last character position for a set of substrings or words appearing in a larger string, for example:

```
StringPosition["TheBrownFox", {"Brown","Fox"}]

out: {{4, 8}, {9, 11}}
```

Now, one of the more interesting parts of this question, IMO, is how we handle overlaps between substrings / words (i.e. `ss1`, `ss2`, `ss3`, etc.).  For example, if we add the nonsense word "wnFo" to the previous example, we have overlapping words:

```
testString = TheBrownFox;
StringPosition[testString, {"Brown","Fox","wnFo"}]

out: {{4, 8}, {7, 10}, {9, 11}}
```

So we need to do a kind of "surgery" on the output list for `StringPosition` s.t. there is never a situation where we have `{..., {integerOne, intTwo}, {intThree, intFour}, ...}` where it is NOT the case that `intOne < intTwo < intThree < intFour`.

Update: Please see Kuba's very slick answer to my question concerning how one might do this: [Identifying and isolating sections of overlap in a set of integer intervals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45135/identifying-and-isolating-sections-of-overlap-in-a-set-of-integer-intervals)

---

I am inspired by this example https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/HighlightWordsOfAGivenLength.html where words of a certain length are highlighted and bolded.

Comment: related: [How to change the color of specified digits in a number?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40754/5478)

Comment: Second that link - very slick methods presented in *Kuba*'s answer.

Comment: @rasher Yeah, I'm going through it now!

Comment: @Kuba I really like your `mark` function - is there a good way to kind of map it over a large number of instances in the format given by `StringPosition`?  What happens if there is a collision where two words specifying different colors overlap?

Comment: As I think the handling of overlaps is the demanding part of your question I'd suggest to make an example with overlaps to provide a good test case for that...

Comment: @AlbertRetey That's a good point.  Hold on please.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Well, I just wrote and posted in the question some really bad code that returns the character positions where overlap between the occurrence of substrings occur.

Comment: Related: [(7008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7008/121), [(7732)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/121), [(10990)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121), [(13312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13312/121)

Answer (score 3):

Using the code for `mark`, [from linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40758/5478):

```
f[string_, cases_] := Module[{pos, agg, res},

   pos = StringPosition[string, cases];

   agg = {Switch[#[[ 1, 2]], 1, Blue, 2, Brown, _, Red], 
          #[[ ;; , {1}]]
         } & /@ GatherBy[Tally@Flatten[Range @@@ pos], Last];

   mark[string, agg]
 ]

f["TheBrownFox", {"TheBrown", "BrownFox"}]
f["TheBrownFox", {"The", "Fox"}]    
f["TheBrownFox", {"The", "eBrownF", "eBrownFox"}]
```

> [image]

Detecting overlaps is based on my code from [Identifying sections of overlaps in a set of integer intervals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45137/5478)

Comment: Shouldn't this already handle any situation where there is an overlap between two or more of the substrings?

Comment: I see, so you were talking about assigning a different color if we have somwething like: f["TheBrownFox", {"The", "eBrownF", "eBrownFox"}]

Comment: That's really great.  I also noticed that you can take the coloration specification, like `Blue` and write `{Large,Blue}` or `{Bold, Blue}`, which is quite nice.

Comment: @Bob2Alice p.s. It is good to hold on with an accpet a day or two. Accept may discorage others, and there could be better ideas :) Yes, it's nice ;P

Comment: Ok, I'm reluctantly unaccept, lol.  If you wouldn't mind, could you add a brief descriptor for your algorithm for detecting the overlap?  I'd just like to make sure I understand.

Comment: @Bob2Alice It is based on your second question. I'm just calculating `Range` for each two positions: `{2,5} - > {2,3,4,5}` and at the end I'm counting occurances with `Tally`. Try to examine the code from that answer and if there are questions feel free to ask. :) Please, delete first 2 comments.

Comment: Ah, I see, makes sense. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you about this, but how do I use FontSize -> ... to be more specific than writing something like {Large,Blue}?  I keep getting errors?

Comment: @Bob2Alice `{Bold, Blue, 18}` should work.

Comment: Ah cool, the documentation for Style/etc. tripped me up.

Comment: Sorry, just one more question - is there a straightforward way to have a different highlight color to each word, like "The" -> Blue, "Brown" -> Brown, "Fox" -> Gray?  Maybe we could have faux intersections to engineer this?

Comment: The "hack" I had in mind was just to input "Fox" multiple times to give it a specific color, and so forth.  This works, but is really inelegant!

Comment: @Bob2Alice I'll try to come back to this later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to achieve what you want. It is neither very elegant nor very efficient, but should do what I think you try to achieve:

```
highlight[text_String, rules_List] := 
 Module[{positions, overlap = Underlined},

  positions = SortBy[
     Flatten[Thread[StringPosition[text, #1] -> #2] & @@@ rules, 1], 
     First
  ];

  positions = positions //. {
     {h___, {s1_, e1_} -> c1_, {s2_, e2_} -> c2_, t___} /; 
       s2 <= e1 :> {
       h,
       {s1, Min[e1, s2] - 1} -> c1,
       {Min[e1, s2], Max[e1, s2]} -> overlap,
       If[e2 >= Max[e1, s2]+1, {Max[e1, s2]+1, e2} -> c2,Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],
       t
       }
     };

  StringReplacePart[text,
    ToString[Style[StringTake[text, #1], #2], StandardForm] & @@@ positions,
    positions[[All, 1]]
  ]
];

highlight[
  "The brown, brown fox with overlapping matches...", 
  {"brown" -> Brown, "fox" -> Red, "app" -> Gray, "lap" -> Orange, "erlapp" -> Green}
 ]
```

The "difficult" part with the overlapping strings I tried to solve with a potentially inefficient pattern matching construct in a `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`). Overlaps are unerlined in the above code but you could of course change that. If efficiency does matter or my approach turns out too be to naive you could try to combine my function with a smarter way to handle these overlaps...