# Identifying and isolating sections of overlap in a set of integer intervals

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very large array like the following:

```
{{1,10},{8,9},{9,20},{34,40},{41,42},{43,50},{47,53},...};
```

Now, imagine that every element in the array corresponds to an integer interval.  I'd like to delete elements in the array that fall within a larger interval, and whenever there is an interval-interval overlap, I'd like to shrink the intersecting intervals to eliminate the overlap and then add the former section where the overlap occurred as a new element to a separate array (here I'm calling this `overlapArray`).

Perhaps this is best explained by example.  Looking at the smaller case:

```
{{1,10},{8,9},{9,20},{34,40}...}
```

We notice that there is an overlap between the first three elements of the array, and that the element `{8,9}` falls entirely in this overlap section.  So we this array becomes the following after our procedure:

```
{{1,7},{11,20},{34,40}...}

overlapArray = {{8,10}};
```

Now for the full example, this:

```
{{1,10},{8,9},{9,20},{34,40},{41,42},{43,50},{47,53},...};
```

Becomes:

```
{{1,7},{11,20},{34,40},{41,42},{43,46},{51,53}

overlapArray = {{8,10},{47,50}};
```

Is there an elegant way to do this with list operations in Mathematica v9?

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, were you preparing a response?  I thought it was too open-ended and that it was a bad question.  I thought from this, and your previous answer, I could figure out how to do it.  But if you have a response, or you think it was wrong for me to do this, I will undelete it!

Comment: @Kuba Whatever you'd like, my priority was just not to be a nuisance here, so I was acting accordingly.

Comment: @Kuba It's back!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like this one :P

```
list = {{1, 10}, {8, 9}, {9, 20}, {34, 40}, {41, 42}, {43, 50}, {47, 53}}

Composition[
 Split[#, #2 - #1 == 1 &][[ All , {1, -1}]] &,
 Sort,
 DeleteCases[#, {_, 1}][[ All , 1]] &,
 Tally,
 Flatten,
 Range @@@ # &
  ][list]
```

> ```
>  {{8, 10}, {47, 50}}
> ```

Comment: This can be written in compact way but now it is more readable.

Comment: Cool!  That sure was fast.   Is there a way to modify the original list to get: {{1,7},{11,20},{34,40},{41,42},{43,46},{51,53}?  BTW, I can't upvote yet due to my low rep.

Comment: @Bob2Alice just change `DeleteCases` to `Cases` :)

Comment: Ooooh nice nice. +1

Comment: Slickly done. +1

Comment: @rasher You are too kind today :) thank you, that's motivating. Bob2Alice, I'm glad you like it :)

Comment: @Bob2Alice In order to examine this code you can start when in `Composition` is only `Range @@ #&` and then, step by step, add one line to see how it works.

Comment: @Kuba I got it now actually, I wasn't sure before what `Range` was doing.  This is a cleverer way that going through and computing `Intersection` multiple times between all of the integers in each interval, right?

Comment: @Bob2Alice Intersection can hadle cases where the limit's are for example `{Pi, Sqrt[2]}` etc. so my solution is nice but not general.

Comment: @Kuba Well, it's the solution to the problem at hand here and probably quite a bit faster than the naive `Intersection` approach.

Comment: @Bob2Alice I think so. But be carefull when the limits start to grow, like `{10^2, 10^10}`, then working with inequalities is better.