# How do I make a single character bold?

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting

I have a string of characters, like

```
"CDABOZPVRYXSWQEGNILUTHMKJF"
```

and want to convert it to a string in which the character at position `p` is bold.

After doing this I want to leave the result in a table that will be displayed in `TableForm` and then used for publications or export — e.g., copy as *LaTeX* — so the result needs to be (essentially) a formatted string with a single bold character.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Here you have more general solution: [How to change the color of specified digits in a number?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40754/5478). You can use it like that: `mark["CDABOZPVRYXSWQEGNILUTHMKJF", {{Red, ;; ;; 2}}]`

Comment: @Kuba That is certainly related.  I wonder if it is a duplicate?  Your Accepted answer there does not produce `String` output however.

Comment: You could use something like `"ABC\!\(\*StyleBox[\"D\",FontWeight->Bold]\)EFG"`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Probably not a duplicate. The problem with keeping it as a string is that next time it is quite tough to specify position. Row is not a the same head too ;P

Comment: @Szabolcs That also produces errors with "Copy as LaTeX" in *Mathematica* 10.0.2.  Is this operation even possible?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Indeed. It looks like *Mathematica* just generates garbage for *LaTeX* even in this simple case. It can't seem to recognized a bold character and just generate `\textbf{x}`.

Comment: I suggest you either post a new question or edit this one to specifically address that problem.  The **Copy as LaTeX** command probably will not be usable but other export may be, given adequate "massaging" of the expressions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Not sure what you mean: the question includes the LaTeX bit. That's the goal here: not merely to get it "bold-looking" but to have the result in a format that can be used as LaTeX. There's no separate question about just making it appear bold.

Comment: Based on the way your question is written I *assumed* that if I returned a styled `String` it would be a solution.  However since *Mathematica* 10.0.2 seems incapable of copying a styled string as LaTeX this is a much different problem.  I suggest that you start with something like "How can I export a styled string to LaTeX?" instead.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I see what you mean. I'll focus this on the formatting (since that's how the answers are focused) and ask a new question about getting the results into LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is related to at least:

- [Highlighting text with StringReplacePart but also using Style, Subscript](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/121)
- [How to join two Style[]d strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121)

Fortunately it is simpler than the first one and we can apply the methods provided in the second one.

```
stringBold[s_String, pos_] :=
 "" <> MapAt[Style[#, Bold] ~ToString~ StandardForm &, Characters@s, pos]

stringBold["CDABOZPVRYXSWQEGNILUTHMKJF", 7]
```

[image]

The output is a `String` with and embedded Box form:

```
% // InputForm
```

> ```
> "CDABOZ\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"P\\\"\", Bold, Rule[StripOnInput, \
> False]]\)VRYXSWQEGNILUTHMKJF"
> ```

Any specification that `MapAt` accepts can be used for parameter `pos`:

```
stringBold["CDABOZPVRYXSWQEGNILUTHMKJF", 2 ;; -3 ;; 3]
```

[image]

However the function *cannot* be applied to more than once, or to an already styled string:

```
stringBold[%, 3]  (* failure *)
```

Comment: This seems to break LaTeX copying. All I get is `\text{` .

Comment: @rax working on it...

Comment: Thanks. It would also be great if this could be applied again to the result (to set additional characters to bold of to other styles).

Comment: @rax Are you expecting the Bold style to be preserved in LaTeX on copy?  I do not see that working at all.  If this is what you mean is *Mathematica* even capable of that?  Or do you just mean that on copy you want a plain string in LaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

```
srF = StringReplacePart[#, ToString[Style[StringTake[#, {#2}], ##3], StandardForm], {#2, #2}] &;

str = "CDABOZPVRYXSWQEGNILUTHMKJF";
srF[str, #, Red, Bold, 16] & /@ {3,9}
```

[image]

Note: Copy as LateX does not work

Comment: This generates non standard LaTeX, such as `\unicode`.