# Two bit strings represented as lists – how to color differing bits as red while printing?

Tags: output-formatting

Assume the following code

```
generatedMsg = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
transmittedMsg = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
```

Now, I want to print out something along these lines:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Generated message:}{}&\; 10001100\\
\text{Transmitted message:}{}&\; 1\color{red}{1}001\color{red}000
\end{align*}
$$

How should I go about doing it?

---

Excuse the $\LaTeX$, but I do not know how to color text by other means.

Comment: In general you may be interested in this [topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40754/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
generatedMsg = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
transmittedMsg = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};

diff = Position[Unitize[generatedMsg - transmittedMsg], 1];

colored = MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, transmittedMsg, diff];

Grid[{
  Prepend[generatedMsg, "Generated message:"],
  Prepend[colored, "Transmitted message:"]
  }, Alignment -> Right]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for both `Unitize` and `MapAt`! I should look at documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

For variety:

```
sF := Style[#, {Black, {Red, Bold}}[[1 + Abs@Subtract@##]]] & @@@ Transpose @ {##} &

Column[Row /@ {##, sF @ ##}] &[transmittedMsg, generatedMsg]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
sF2 := Style[#, {Black, {Red, Bold}}[[1+ #2]]]& @@Transpose@{# , Unitize@Subtract@##} &
```