# Colorize letters in the given string

Tags: string-manipulation

How can I colorize letters in the given string?

For instance:

```
string = "jaonvtaqhsy"
```

How to colorize 3 letters in the middle of `string` (e,g, "vta")?

I tried:

Split the given `string` in the three parts

```
a=StringTake[string, {1, 4}]
b=StringTake[string, {5, 7}]
c=StringTake[string, {8, 11}]
```

and then colorize each string

```
aa = Style[a, Blue, Bold]
bb = Style[b, Red, Bold]
cc = Style[c, Blue, Bold]
```

then join them back together

```
StringJoin[aa,bb,cc]
```

or

```
aa <> bb <> cc
```

but there is an error message

[image]

Comment: Try `Row@{aa,bb,cc}`. Also, your string either needs to be 11 characters long, or `c` should only take `{8,10}` This will work for some applications, but may not be flexible depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Also, test the form of `aa` and `bb` with `Head` or `TreeForm` and you will see they are not `Strings` after you apply the `Style` function  eg,   `Head@aa`

Comment: @N.J.Evans thanks. there is my mistake (10 instead of 11)

Comment: closely related: [How to change the color of specified digits in a number?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40754/5478)

Comment: maybe a duplicate: [Highlighting or coloring certain words / substrings appearing in a larger string](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45132/5478)

Comment: Let me suggest to the poser he delete unneeded portions of the question.  There is no need to see how the string was generated (using RandomChoice), for instance.

Comment: @Kuba please vote to close as one of those.  I shall add http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121 as well.

Comment: Related: [(7008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7008/121), [(7732)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/121), [(10990)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121), [(13312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13312/121)

Comment: @Kuba Did you choose not to vote to close this as a duplicate?  If so may I know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
highlight[mystring_String, where_List] :=

 Row@{StringTake[mystring, {1, where[[1]] - 1}], 
      Style[StringTake[mystring, where], Red], 
      StringTake[mystring, {where[[2]] + 1, StringLength[mystring]}]}

highlight["abcdefghijkl", {3, 5}]
```

If you want to highlight a single character,

```
highlight["abcdefghijkl", {3, 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "jaonvtaqhsy"; 
a = StringTake[string, {1, 4}];
b = StringTake[string, {5, 7}];
c = StringTake[string, {8, 11}];
aa = Style[a, Blue, Bold]; 
bb = Style[b, Red, Bold]; 
cc = Style[c, Blue, Bold]; 
ToString[#1, FormatType -> StandardForm] & @ Row[{aa, bb, cc}]
```

produces a colored string.